# With respect to char pointer, how does the sizeof operator work?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Below is the code (compiled with gcc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *c="hello";
    printf("1) sizeof 'hello' : %d \n",sizeof("hello"));
    printf("2) sizeof '*c' : %d \n",sizeof(*c));
    printf("3) sizeof 'c': %d \n",sizeof(c));
    printf("4) sizeof '&c' : %d \n",sizeof(&c));
    printf("5) sizeof '&hello': %d \n",sizeof(&("hello")));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the given program:

```
1) sizeof 'hello' : 6                                                                               
2) sizeof '*c' : 1                                                                                  
3) sizeof 'c': 8                                                                                    
4) sizeof '&c' : 8                                                                                  
5) sizeof '&hello': 8
```

So, for case 1) and 2) there is no problem why this output.
But for the remaining cases, i.e. 3), 4) and 5), why does the `sizeof` operator give 8?

As per my knowledge `&c`, `c` and `&"hello"` represent the same thing i.e. a group of characters (i.e. `c` is pointing to 'hello') and `*c` represents a single char (i.e. `*c` is pointing to 'h').

So, why is `sizeof(c)` giving 8 and not 6? From what calculation is this 8 coming?

Comment: It's actually a pointer to the first element of char array, thus 8bytes on x64 architecture

Comment: @Quest Thanks. Got it. I forgot about the 64bit arch. as I was running code on online gcc and assumed that server is 32 bit machine.

Comment: "represent the same thing" – no, they don't represent the same thing. The numeric value of their pointers may be the same, but they have nothing else in common. The three pointers have same type (`char *`, `char **` and `char (*)[6]`), and are conceptually very different. (one points to a character, the second one points to the pointer, and the third one points to an array.)

Comment: BTW, it is undefined behavior to format the result of `sizeof` using the `%d` conversion specifier. `%d` is for `int`, but the value of `sizeof` is `size_t`, for which the correct conversion specifier is `%zu`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`sizeof` solely inspects the type of the argument**, never its value.
`"hello"` is an lvalue of type `char const[6]`. The size of an array object is simply the size of the elements times the bound. The size of `char` is defined to be 1, hence `sizeof *c` is 1, and `sizeof "hello"` is 6*1=6.

Pointers are usually 4 or 8 bytes large - on your platform it's 8,  as indicated by the value of
`sizeof c`.
`sizeof (&c)` and `sizeof(&("hello"))` give you the same output as `sizeof c`. Again, simply the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`c` is a pointer to `char`. Size of any pointer on a 64-bit system is 8 bytes.

`"hello"` is an array of chars (actually, `char const[6]`). That's why `sizeof("hello")` is 6.

When you write `c = "hello";`, the array `"hello"` decays to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: "Size of any pointer on a 64-bit system is 8 bytes." --> Although common, this is not specified to be true.  "64-bit system" typically refers to the processor width, not the memory capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Those are far from the same:

1. "hello" is an array of six chars.
2. c is a pointer (to a char).
3. &c is also a pointer (to a pointer).
4. &"hello" is a pointer (to an array of six chars).

In some cases, these behave the same, because char arrays decay to char pointers in some use cases. However, that is a conversion and it doesn't change what they are!